# How to Get Labels to Line Up

Tags: html, css, tags, alignment, label

[image]
[image]

I'm almost done with my Calculator Application. The last thing that I have to do is to get the two labels ("First Number:" and "Second Number:") to line up perfectly. I would like to move "First Number:" to the right a little bit so that the colon : lines up with the colon below it. I've tried assigning the label a class and moving it right in the CSS, but this is moving the textbox to the right as well. Here is my full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Calculator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="calculator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<label> </label>
<input class="noLabel" type="text" id="sum" disabled="disabled">
<br>
<label>First Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstNumber">    
<br>
<label>Second Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="secondNumber">
<br>

<div>
<input type="button" id="calc" value="Calculate">
<input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
</div>

</section>
</body>

</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
input:not([type="button"]) {
margin-left: -5em;
margin-bottom: .5em;
}

input.noLabel {
margin-left:11em;
background-color: Beige;
color: blue;
}


label {
width: 11em;
float:left;

}

h1 {
color:black;
text-align:center;
}

section {
padding: 0 2em 1em;
border: grey solid; 
background-color: #DCDCDC;
width: 350px;
}

div {
margin-left: 7.5em;
}
```

As always, thanks for your help!

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi,I don't get what you want ?
Describe it with image what you actually want.

Comment: The new photo below the original shows what I'm trying to do..."First Number:" is shifted to the right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to replicate the expected output for the label. You just need to use `text-align: right` on the labels with a width that is slightly greater than the label text as the text will be lined up at the extreme right end.

But I recommend using this layout: [**Forms Horizontal**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) which is better and easily manageable to edit.

```css
input:not([type="button"]) {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 0.6em; /* Modified */
}
input.noLabel {
  margin-left: 11em;
  background-color: Beige;
  color: blue;
}
label {
  float: left;
  text-align: right; /* Added */
  width: 140px; /* Modified */
}
h1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
section {
  padding: 0 2em 1em;
  border: grey solid;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  width: 350px;
}
div {
  margin-left: 7.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="calculator.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <label></label>
    <input class="noLabel" type="text" id="sum" disabled="disabled">
    <br>
    <label>First Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstNumber">
    <br>
    <label>Second Number:</label>
    <input type="text" id="secondNumber">
    <br>

    <div>
      <input type="button" id="calc" value="Calculate">
      <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
    </div>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately your modifications resulted in the picture above (last picture in the post). Even though it works in your code snippet, I would still have to move the labels and text boxes back to the left again.